# What does stop streaming builds ans start streaming builds does in google cloud build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

In build history I'm seeing a new button saying stop streaming builds, what does it mean in google cloud build[image]

Comment: and even my cloud build console UI also changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems to be pushing a new UI.
Monday I was getting it every so often, yesterday I got it all day.
The "Stop Streaming" stops the page from auto updating.

The old UI, had a "refresh" button as new builds would not show automatically

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it with a few test examples and it seems like the only thing it does is stop showing you the creation of new builds in the UI, until you refresh the page.